# How to move the Storybook Notes tab to addons panel

Tags: storybook, storybook-addon-specifications

I need Notes addon to appear in the addon panels but at the moment it appears as a tab.

I have tried registering it as a panel as advised by the npm Readme but that breaks the app

```
// or register the notes addon as a panel. Only one can be used!

import '@storybook/addon-notes/register-panel';
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/addon-notes/v/5.1.0-alpha.25

I would like to move the Notes tab to the addons panel:

[image]

Comment: Would love to know this too!

Comment: I opened an issue: https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/6852